# How do i get all info from a paginated json service and show it in reverse order in angular?

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova, pagination, reverse

I'm pinging a service that returns a JSON array of 20 items. There may be 20+ pages. What I want to so is get all of the information and store it in one object so that i can show the array in the reverse order.

This is for a cordova application.

So basically how do i bypass the pagination and repaginate the information in the reverse order?

Thanks for your help.

Keith

Answer (score 1):

just reverse the array you get from JSON before the pagination

array.reverse() is what you need